# d3.js - After translate wrong mouse coordinates being reported. Why?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3.js to draw a rectangle with it's top-left corner at (10,10). 
Then I move that rectangle by doing a `translate(200, 200)`.

Then I attach an on-mouseout event that simply prints out the coordinates of the mouse pointer. To my surprise the coordinates it reports indicate the boundaries of the rectangle **before it was translated**. Why???

How can I make it report the actual mouse-coordinates, not the mouse coordinates of where the rectangle used to be before it was translated?

Here is the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.svgContainer = d3.select("#my_svg_widget");

    var my_rect = self.svgContainer.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("width", 60)
      .attr("height", 60);

    my_rect.attr("transform", "translate(200, 200)");    

    my_rect.on("mouseover", function() {
        var coordinates = [0, 0];
        coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
        var mouseX6 = Number(coordinates[0]);
        var mouseY6 = Number(coordinates[1]);
        console.log('mouseX6 = ', mouseX6, typeof mouseX6);
        console.log('mouseY6 = ', mouseY6, typeof mouseY6);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Here is the output:

```
mouseX6 =  13 number
mouseY6 =  9 number
```

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/VSTzUhehdsVLFgmZqzHi?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **d3.mouse** -> Find x,y coordinates of the current mouse event relative to a container element.

Try this code:

```
var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
var pt = self.svgContainer.node().createSVGPoint();
pt.x = coordinates[0];
pt.y = coordinates[1];
pt = pt.matrixTransform(my_rect.node().getCTM());
var mouseX6 = pt.x, mouseY6 = pt.y;
```

**Updated plunker:**
Try clicking on the rect to test the new position calculation.

```js
var self = {};
self.svgContainer = d3.select("#my_svg_widget");

console.log("Hello!");

var my_rect = self.svgContainer.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("width", 60)
  .attr("height", 60)
  .attr("fill", "Pink")
  .attr("stroke", "Blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2);

my_rect.attr("transform", "translate(200, 200)");

my_rect.on("mouseover", function() {
  console.log("\n\n\n================ MouseOver Rectangle ================");
  var coordinates = [0, 0];
  console.log("1");
  coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
  var pt = self.svgContainer.node().createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = coordinates[0];
  pt.y = coordinates[1];
  pt = pt.matrixTransform(my_rect.node().getCTM());
  //coordinates = d3.mouse(self.svgContainer);
  console.log("2");
  var mouseX6 = Number(coordinates[0]);
  var mouseY6 = Number(coordinates[1]);
  console.log('mouseX6 = ', mouseX6, typeof mouseX6);
  console.log('mouseY6 = ', mouseY6, typeof mouseY6);

  mouseX6 = pt.x;
  mouseY6 = pt.y;
  console.log('mouseX6 = ', mouseX6, typeof mouseX6);
  console.log('mouseY6 = ', mouseY6, typeof mouseY6);
});

my_rect.on("click", function() {
  console.log("\n\n\n================ Click on Rectangle ================");

  var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
  var pt = self.svgContainer.node().createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = coordinates[0];
  pt.y = coordinates[1];
  pt = pt.matrixTransform(my_rect.node().getCTM());
  var mouseX6 = pt.x,
    mouseY6 = pt.y;
  self.svgContainer.append("circle").attr("cx", pt.x).attr("cy", pt.y).attr("r", 3);
  console.log('mouseX6 = ', mouseX6, typeof mouseX6);
  console.log('mouseY6 = ', mouseY6, typeof mouseY6);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="my_svg_widget" width="300" height="300" style="border-style:solid;border-color:purple;border-width: 2px;">
</svg>
```

Comment: I didn't try the first option. But the second option you showed is not correct. Here is the new plunker containing it: https://plnkr.co/edit/VSTzUhehdsVLFgmZqzHi?p=preview. When you enter the square at the top-left corner, it should report (approximately) X=210, Y=210. Instead it reports X=220, Y=220.